# Why doesn't this recipe show up in Google Recipes search results?

Tags: microformats, rich-snippets

I have [this blog post](http://www.amateurgourmet.com/2012/08/drunk-blondies.html) which has been encoded with rich text snippets (microformats) to indicate a number of fields to Google, including a full recipe with ingredients, the author, the cook time and prep time, a photo, etc.

According to [Google's guidelines](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=173379), I have enough fields that it should be showing up, and Google's [rich text snippets tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http://www.amateurgourmet.com/2012/08/drunk-blondies.html) is showing no errors for that page.

Yet-- no love from Google. Why?

Answer (score 0):

for starters, you need to have two of the following classes: 
`photo`
`prepTime` or `cookTime` or `totalTime` or `ingredients`
`calories`
`review` (nested)

i checked the first one, `photo`, while you do have two on your page, they are the same image, as well as the second is set to `display:none`. not sure which or if both are throwing it off. i would start their first. then ensure that i have all of the other requirements.

Comment: Thank you. My page has cooktime, preptime, ingredients and photo, so that's 4 of the recipe fields (and Google only asks for at least 2 of them to be there). I see what you mean about the photo being hidden, that's a side effect of Typepad Connect commenting system which I can't really change. Soooo... I'm not sure that's the problem but I appreciate your feedback...

Comment: --and, FWIW, again, the Google Rich Snippets Test Tool is giving me all green lights. Which is so frustrating :-)

Comment: ah snap; i read that wrong, i thought each had to be in there 2x...mb. well i did notice your meta description was broken, but that's not it. try pinging google to make sure they know that post has been published. also read this page and make sure you are in compliance: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1093493   and lastly, tell google that they're not showing up here: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/request.py?&contact_type=rich_snippets_feedback

Comment: I'll give all that a shot! Thanks.